# Loading speed of ImageView

Tags: android, performance

I'm trying to load an activity with some ImageView as soon as possible, and I noticed that the performances are much better if I use the following attributes

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

instead of this

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/attachment_image"
android:layout_height="@dimen/attachment_image"
```

with @dimen/attachment_image defined as

```
<dimen name="attachment_image">130dp</dimen>
```

in the *dimens.xml*. 
It seems that the resizing of the ImageView is affecting the loading speed... do someone knows a way to correct this?

Comment: NOt sure of the speed but if you give fix dimensions like this, your image might look smaller or larger on different screen size phone or tablet. If its ok with you?

Comment: Obviously enough, a scaling process is a process. So it takes its time to work. An unscaled image doesn't require the scaling process time... and loads faster than a scaled one.

Comment: If the image's true dimension is different than the defined one (130dp), Android system will rescale it at runtime, which does have its associated cost. But unless you are running on ancient hw or there are tons of these images, otherwise the performance difference shouldn't be that noticeable. But if you are certain this is the source of the problem, one way is to only start loading the images after the Activity is shown.

Comment: @Vyger it sholdnt be any noticable difgerence, there is no scaling of Bitmaps inside ImageView

Comment: @Kai it shouldnt be any noticable difference, there is no scaling of Bitmaps inside ImageView

Comment: As Kai pointed out, it depends on how many of these images are there and the devices's hardware. In all, it's NOT an issue. Just a consideration.

Comment: @Vyger no it doesnt depend on this, again: ImageView does not scale any Bitmap under the hood

Comment: @pskink: No, **if it's set to wrap_content** or if it's used as **src** (as opposed to background); **yes** if it's set to a fixed dimension or to match_parent (as per the OP's question) or even as background (which is stretched anyway).

Comment: @Vyger i am sorry you are wrong: ImageView does not scale any Bitmaps, see https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java and show me the line where Bitmap is scaled

Comment: @pskink have you checked the src? Line 932-954 contains various conditions for drawing a Bitmap, and the last condition (else, line 986-993) is scaling the Bitmap.

Comment: @pskink: If it makes you happy, I'll tell you that I'm wrong and you're right, OK? But YOU really should read that code deeply.

Comment: @Vyger and where is that Bitmap scaling? Matrix transformation has nothing to do with Bitmap scaling like Bitmap.createScaledBitmap() method. if you start ScaleAnimation to you really think that android creates N scaled Bitmaps when it wants to draw that anmimation in N frames?

Comment: Yes, it will. Anyway, tell me how do you explain that if I specify a layout_width or height for an Image , say in dp, the image scales? In the src it's doing resizing (which is also synonim to scaling) and rescaling everywhere...

Comment: @Vyger so you think if in onDraw i do: canvas.scale(100, 100); canvas.drawBitmap(btm, 0, 0, null) android creates Bitmap that is 100 times bigger than btm? think it twice

Comment: ... who was talking about drawing in code?! We were talking of the ImageView object per se.

Comment: @Vyger and imageView does not call canvas.drawBitmap? hmmm, strange

Comment: It doesn't. Reread [this](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java) and find it, if you can. See, you are trying to be sarcastic, with the result of being ridicolous. For me, we can stop it here.

Comment: ok then see line 1047 mDrawable.draw(canvas); for a Bitmap to be drawn a BitmapDrawable is used https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.java see its draw(Canvas) method line 493, and who is ridicolous?

Comment: @Vyger mDrawable.draw(canvas) is also called in line #1026 this time with no Canvas transformation

Comment: So, explain me why the imageview is scaled when you specify a value which is other than wrap_content (or just explain me the background stretching): in your opinion this doesn't happen. But it really does.

Comment: @Vyger it uses a Matrix, matrix can be scaled and transkated (if scale type is center) and then the key method is Canvas.concat(Matrix) which more or less is equal to Canvas.scale/Canvas.translate/Canvas.rotate then after. canvas is transformed simple Canvas.drawBitmap is called, note that you dont have to concat the Canvas for drawing just a Bitmap, Canvas.drawBitmap with Matrix param can be used

Comment: So, independent of what it uses, it becomes scaled. The CPU (or the GPU) does some work. So, the concept remains that it consumes more time (for as transcurable as it can be) than an unscaled ImageView. And this is what started the flame...

Comment: @Vyger it was not flame, and yes, GPU is a key word here so i can scale the Canvas by factor of 1000000 and still you will not see any difference... and iven so its not seconds that OP saw in his app (see how smoothly ScaleAnimation runs)

Comment: Not even on an OLD 2.2 device (2.8", the old glorious Huawei Ideos 8150), which has a CPU that runs at 600 MHz and has no GPU (the Italian version hasn't got it - other versions have the adreno 130). so it's all in charge to the poor CPU. By the way, I use it for compatibility and performance tests.

Comment: @Vyger funny thing is that i have the device with the same old poor cpu MSM7225, i use it to make sure that my code will run smoothly even it that low end device

Comment: @pskink: It's old, but still useful to me. ;)